# startForegroundService - Specify a custom 'background app running..' notification?

Tags: android, service, notifications, foreground

I have a foreground service that I launch via `startForegroundService`.

All works great.

The only thing I am unable to figure out is how to / if its possible to customize the "...is running in the background' notification.

The notification I am sending over to `startForeground` looks like this:

```
Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_icon)
.setContentTitle("My title")
.setContentText("My content")
.build();

startForeground(1, notification);
```

I am then presented by android with the standard "...running in background" notification, with my custom one no where to be seen.

Am I doing something wrong?

Not looking to hide it or anything nefarious, but would like to use it more as a status of what the background service is actually doing... Which sounds like an ideal use case for this sort of thing.

For what its worth, I am running Android 8 and targeting SDK 26 as that is the latest available for my handset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Create and Manage Notification Channels guide](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels):

> Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel.

Your notification is not appearing because you do not set a notification channel as per the note on that same page:

> Caution: If you target Android 8.0 (API level 26) and post a notification without specifying a notification channel, the notification does not appear and the system logs an error.

> Note: You can turn on a new setting in Android 8.0 (API level 26) to display an on-screen warning that appears as a toast when an app targeting Android 8.0 (API level 26) attempts to post without a notification channel. To turn on the setting for a development device running Android 8.0 (API level 26), navigate to Settings > Developer options and enable Show notification channel warnings.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I did have a channel... But I had the importance set to IMPORTANCE_NONE... Also looks like once a channel is created, the settings stick (at least in 26 / 8?) and any changes mean a new channel ID needs to be made.

Comment: Channels are not editable after creation, that's correct.